# Is there any other way to make Standard Picklist field as a Dependent pick list field

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

Hi I have set a Field dependency for a custom and standard pick list field.

The challenge is When I try to do it The Standard pick list field is not shown in the Dependency options.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Please provide your Ideas on this.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Dependent Picklist Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en)

> Standard versus custom picklists
>
> Custom picklist fields can be either controlling or dependent fields. 
>   **Standard picklist fields can be controlling fields but not dependent fields**.

Hence, Standard Picklist fields are not avaialble in Depedency option.

Comment: Any out of Box solution for this.

Comment: As of now, No. Here is an idea for the same. You can vote for this idea, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrnIAAS